# Backup and Restore using adb

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, adb, data-transfer, htc-legend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New phone: How to transfer game progress?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21112/new-phone-how-to-transfer-game-progress)

I recently got a Samsung Galaxy S3 and I am wanting to transfer my Jetpack Joyride game progress from my old HTC Legend. There are 2 things I am unsure of when it comes to using adb. Is there a way to us it to get the data from my HTC or will I need to root it. I read in a few places that it doesn't work on Android 2.2. Also, what commands would I use to restore the data to the Samsung?

Answer (score 1):

`adb backup –apk –shared –all –f /backup/mybackup.ab` - backs up your all apps and data.

`adb restore /backup/mybackup.ab` - restores it back.