# adb backup probably fails when trying to backup a single application

Tags: adb, backup, restore

Following the advice here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38277/27533, I am trying to migrate the application from Nexus 7 to ASUS ME302C. (Actually, my daughter desperately needs that -- you know, all that work with Pou ;)

It seems I have successfully installed drivers for both Nexus 7 and the ASUS on my PC with Windows 7. I can copy files from and to both devices.

The backup process seemingly works correctly as it creates the `backup.ab` after running the command `adb backup me.pou.app`. I did not use the `-apk` as I want only the data. The created `backup.ab` has about 2.5 KB which seems reasonable. However, the `adb backup –apk me.pou.app` and `adb backup –apk –shared me.pou.app` commands produce the `backup.ab` of exactly the same size (2623 bytes)`; however, they differ when compared in binary mode.

There is no error reported. The Nexus 7 (the source of the backup) shows always `Backup the data` button at the bottom right (translated). The first toast says the process was started, the second toast says, it was finished.

I do not know what should I try, check, or whatever to make it working.

Comment: Just a guess: it might be the app is "protected", and ADB thus doesn't grab the `.apk` but instead a corresponding note into the backup. You might try with e.g. the [Helium App Sync and Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/helium-app-sync-and-backup/com.koushikdutta.backup) app, which does an ADB backup directly on the device, whether it gives any additional clue (as the name of the app suggests, you could even use this app to "sync" the app+data to the other device).

Comment: Actually, I did try the Helium earlier. However, the restore for the Pou stopped -- freezed. I just did try Helium to backup newly installed Pou on the new machine (only the data; I can send it if you want and tell me where -- zipped about 9 KB). Then I tried to restore it from the internal storage immediately, on the same machine. It freezed at 71 % (repeated with the same result). It also says that there were some error -- sent to ClockworkMod. No luck. With another application (Subway Surf is also inevitable :) it freezed at 1 % (much bigger).