# Moving app data from galaxy phone to tablet

Tags: applications

I want to transfer a game with my progress form my phone to my tablet. The game is in my Google play account but it does not show my progress when I open the game. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at [New phone: How to transfer game progress?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21112/16575) and [other related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=transfer+game+data+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 0):

If the devices are rooted you can use a program called [Data Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quintstoffers.DataSync.beta)

If it's not rooted, you can use a program called [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)